# ListItem date field is one day off when uploading document

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've a service that uploads documents to SharePoint Online and assigns the respective metadata to it. 
Everything works fine except the date fields that are always one day off.

Eg: If I assign the date 01/05/2016 while uploading the document, when I see it's properties on SharePoint Online it states 30/04/2016.

For the website my regional settings are the following:

[image: Regional Settings]
Column settings are simple:

[image: Column settings]

In the background i'm parsing the date like this:

```
Return DateTime.Parse(strValue).ToUniversalTime().ToString(System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Any suggestion on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the ToUniversalTime(). Use it like :
Return DateTime.Parse(strValue).ToString(System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo). 

ToUniversalTime converts date to UTC format. So maybe because of that the dates are off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToUniversalTime()` converts your date to UTC format. Remove the section and it should work fine.

Remove the `ToUniversalTime()`. Use it like :

```
Return DateTime.Parse(strValue).ToString(System.Globalization.DateT‌​imeFormatInfo.Invari‌​antInfo)
```

`ToUniversalTime` converts date to UTC format. So maybe because of that the dates are off.